# org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException:

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, svn

I download trunk openam through svn(https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/trunk/openam/), and import it in  eclipse. When I maven install it,I get Exception as follows:
[ERROR] 
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: The path 'F:\svn_openam' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.open(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:197)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.doOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:366)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:274)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:267)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:263)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:317)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:476)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:441)
    at oe.maven.plugins.revision.RevisionMojo.getEntryProperties(RevisionMojo.java:152)
    at oe.maven.plugins.revision.RevisionMojo.execute(RevisionMojo.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

At First I think it could be svn problem, so i drop svn software. After that I find problem remains, I wonder how to solve it?

Comment: What about `svn: The path 'F:\svn_openam' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy. Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this working copy. at `. So you are using an older subversion client (you have done svn checkout...) you have to update your subversion client.

Comment: The subversion that I use is TortoiseSVN-1.8.7.25475-win32-svn-1.8.9.1401257396.msi. It supposed to be version 1.8

Comment: I Talked about your ide, cause i assume you have imported that into Eclipse where you need having an appropriate SVN connector like Subclipse etc. which you should update.